# How to handle remote monitoring of log4j?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I´ve been using [chainsaw](http://logui.sourceforge.net/) to remotely monitor an application that use log4j. I´m wondering if there are better ways to do it, or perhaps another logging framework.

Comment: What issues are you having that you are looking to improve upon?

Comment: I have several applications and I want to have a central log server, a client should register to the central server choose the application and see the log.
I checked some of the recommedantios (logFaces, Splunk) but I will prefer a non-commercial solution.

Answer (score 7):

Try [OtrosLogViewer](http://code.google.com/p/otroslogviewer)

**Disclaimer**: I am the author of OtrosLogViewer

Answer (score 4):

Try [logFaces](http://www.logfaces.com)

**Disclosure**: I am the author of this product.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with chainsaw, it is good. If you need something more, look at the log4j [appenders](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Appender.html). If you read all of the documentation with log4j you will see that the appenders can send logs to email, cell phones.....

Answer (score 2):

We have built some JMX beans (the ones that come with log4j are not very friendly) that can display/scan/truncate/copy log files. As WolfmanDragon pointed out, you can use custom appenders to send your log messages to other destinations. Combined with a filter, you can send log4j error messages to a management application using JMX notifications, etc.

If you have absolutely massive amount of logging over many machines, you can use something like [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/).

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few Java logging tools out there (see a list at [Java-logging.com](http://www.java-logging.com/)), so it really depends on your specific needs. For real-time monitoring, log files or remote logging to a log server, you might want to take a look at our Java logging tool [SmartInspect](http://www.gurock.com/smartinspect/).